# Deploy iPhone application to AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, deployment, app-store

May be this question seems to be stupid, but strangely I find it hard to deploy an application to the AppStore, specially that I'm from Morocco and we don't have a specific AppStore for our country, also I found something about using iTunes connect, but I cannot access to this with My newly created AppleID, does any body know any simple way (or complicated) to deploy a Free and/or Not Free application ?

Thanks in advance :) and sorry for this kind question :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pay the $99 (per year) to join the complete iOS Developer Programme. Once you have done that there are good guides available within the developer account.

Comment: ok, thanks, but do I need to pay even if I'm whilling to put only free apps ?

Comment: Yes you do. You also need it to test your application on your actual device (rather than just on the simulator).

Answer (score 1):

You need an iTunesConnect account to publish apps to AppStore. If you can't login with your credentials you need to ask the admin to send you an invitation to it. If you don't know who is the admin you should ask it from a person who has the leading role of the developers. Basically all you need can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/index.html

Hope it helps